# Android Studio 4.2 how to use my framework.jar replace android.jar compile my project

Tags: android

```
allprojects {

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs.add('-Xbootclasspath/p:framework/framework.jar')
    }
}
```

}

This code works well in 4.0 and below, does not work after upgrade 4.2, But I'd love to experience the new version

Has anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            Set<File> fileSet = options.bootstrapClasspath.getFiles()
            List<File> newFileList =  new ArrayList<>();
             newFileList.add(new File("./app/lib/framework.jar"))
            newFileList.addAll(fileSet)
            options.bootstrapClasspath = files(
                    newFileList.toArray()
            )
```

Comment: I found that it seems that the buildToolsVersion affected the build.More than "31.0.0" failed again